# Sending Local notifications when the app is in background mode not working

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer, nsnotifications

I want to be able to send multiple local notifications throughout the day, this must also work in background mode and it must work on a timer, so every 20 minutes to be exact. The problem I am having is that once in background mode they are not firing because the function used to set the timer will not run.

I have then thought about running the timer in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` but this would clash with the original timer set in the function.

Is there anyway for this to work basically? Any wisdom would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) and perfrom your task in background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```